# Can I use PCL that are used building Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android version, to build windows app version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am new to Xamarin platform, so this question may have simple answer. If there are duplicate questions please forgive. But I need help from you.

I have developed Android and iOS version of an app using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. I have used PCL based solution, where all of my business logic, models, code for consuming REST API etc. are in a Portable class library. Android and iOS project are using these shared code using interfaces. I follow Model-view-presenter architecture.

Now I have to develop windows phone version of this app. So my question is, can I use my Core PCL in Xamarin.Forms project to use in Windows phone app? Can you give me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is a page here which details the PCL profiles and which platforms they can be used on:

http://portablelibraryprofiles.apps.stephencleary.com/

If you are using Xamarin Studio you can go to the properties of your PCL project then Build -> General and select the platforms your want to support - the most appropriate profile will be selected for you.

You can also do something similar in Visual Studio by going to Properties -> Library and changing the target frameworks.

More information on this, and PCLs in general, can be found at our guide:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#Editing_PCL_Settings